# Math Comparison on 2 Numbers with Multiple Decimals

Tags: c#

I need to compare section numbers in a document, at first I was just going to convert to decimal and check to see if one number is greater than another.
The issue there is that some sections have multiple decimals.

Example: I need to perform a math comparison on 1.1 with 1.1.2.3 to determine which one is farther along in a document.

They are strings to begin with and I need to do some math comparisons on them essentially.
I though about removing the decimals then converting to int but this throws off certain sections, like section 2 would be considered less than section 1.1 since 1.1 would be changed to a 11, which is no good.

```
    string section1 = "1.1";
    string section2 = "2";
    int convertedSection1 = Convert.ToInt32(section1.Replace(".",""));
    int convertedSection2 = Convert.ToInt32(section2.Replace(".",""));
    if(convertedSection1 < convertedSection2)
        //This will incorrectly say 1.1 is greater than 2

    string section1 = "1.1.2.4";
    string section2 = "2.4";
    decimal convertedSection1 = Convert.ToDecimal(section1);
    decimal convertedSection2 = Convert.ToDecimal(section2);
    if(convertedSection1 < convertedSection2)
        //This will convert 1.1.2.4 to 1.1 which is no good
```

Comment: 1.1.2.4 must be converted to 1.124?

Comment: //This will convert 1.1.2.4 to 1.1 which is no good - what do you expect here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a class similar to the `Version` class of the .NET framework. If you implement some operators and `IComparable`, it's really nice.

How does it work? It will convert the given string into a list of integer numbers. Upon comparison, it will start at the beginning of each list and compare each individual part.

```
public class Section: IComparable<Section>
{
    // Stores all individual components of the section
    private List<int> parts = new List<int>();

    // Construct a section from a string
    public Section(string section)
    {
        var strings = section.Split('.');
        foreach (var s in strings)
        {
            parts.Add(int.Parse(s));
        }
    }

    // Make it nice for display
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return  string.Join(".", parts);
    }

    // Implement comparison operators for convenience
    public static bool operator ==(Section a, Section b)
    {
        // Comparing the identical object
        if (ReferenceEquals(a, b)) return true;

        // One object is null and the other isn't
        if ((object)a == null) return false;
        if ((object)b == null) return false;

        // Different amount of items
        if (a.parts.Count != b.parts.Count) return false;

        // Check all individual items
        for (int i=0; i<a.parts.Count;i++)
        {
            if (a.parts[i] != b.parts[i]) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Section a, Section b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

    public static bool operator <(Section a, Section b)
    {
        // Use minimum, otherwise we exceed the index
        for (int i=0; i< Math.Min(a.parts.Count, b.parts.Count); i++)
        {
            if (a.parts[i] < b.parts[i]) return true;
        }

        if (b.parts.Count > a.parts.Count) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static bool operator >(Section a, Section b)
    {
        // Use minimum, otherwise we exceed the index
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(a.parts.Count, b.parts.Count); i++)
        {
            if (a.parts[i] > b.parts[i]) return true;
        }

        if (a.parts.Count > b.parts.Count) return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Implement the IComparable interface for sorting
    public int CompareTo(Section other)
    {
        if (this == other) return 0;
        if (this < other) return -1;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Tests for 96% coverage:

```
Assert.IsTrue(new Section("1.2.3.4") > new Section("1.2.3"));
Assert.IsFalse(new Section("1.2.3.4") < new Section("1.2.3"));
Assert.IsFalse(new Section("1.2.3.4") == new Section("1.2.3"));
Assert.IsTrue(new Section("1.2.3.4") == new Section("1.2.3.4"));
Assert.IsFalse(new Section("1.2.3.4") == new Section("1.2.3.5"));
Assert.IsTrue(new Section("1.2.3.4") != new Section("1.2.3.5"));
var sec = new Section("1");
Assert.IsTrue(sec == sec);

Assert.AreEqual("1.2.3.4", new Section("1.2.3.4").ToString());

var sortTest = new List<Section> { new Section("2"), new Section("1.2"), new Section("1"), new Section("3.1") };
sortTest.Sort();
var expected = new List<Section> { new Section("1"), new Section("1.2"), new Section("2"), new Section("3.1") };
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, sortTest, new SectionComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your section strings are always well formed, and you know that they don't go deeper than 6 levels, and that no level has more than 999 items, then this works nicely:

```
string zero = ".0.0.0.0.0.0";
long Section2Long(string section) =>
    (section + zero)
        .Split('.')
        .Take(6)
        .Select(t => long.Parse(t))
        .Aggregate((x, y) => x * 1000 + y);
```

Now, if I have this:

```
string[] sections = new []
{
    "1.2.4", "2.3", "1", "1.2", "1.1.1.1", "1.0.0.1.0.1", "2.2.9"
};
```

I can easily sort it like this:

```
string[] sorted = sections.OrderBy(x => Section2Long(x)).ToArray();
```

I get this output:

```
1 
1.0.0.1.0.1 
1.1.1.1 
1.2 
1.2.4 
2.2.9 
2.3
```